# Running DB2 java stored procedures in single process

Tags: java, db2

It seems, that DB2 creates new process for each connection when running java stored procedures in it (for example, procedures, which are called from trigger on some table update event).
The question is: is any way for running all java stored procedures in single process, so we could share static values between them?

Comment: Hmmm, I would be surprised if you could do this.  What, exactly are you trying to do?  There are other ways of sharing values (such as using the database).

Comment: Well. I need to write some logging (in files) in background. For this purpose I start a Thread. Some triggers call my stored java procedure, which puts some object in Queue for further processing by this Thread. The problem is that for multiple connections I can't share this singleton thread.

Comment: why not make the queue be a table?  Then your single thread can poll the table once in awhile to see if there are any objects that need processing.

Comment: No, sorry. It is not a way, because of I'm logging update/insert/delete operations on many tables in a convenient for me mode. We have a deal with a high-loaded database, that is why I need background process for all slow operations such as writing to file. By the way separate table for dumping changes in many tables is not applicable: deleting from it is a very cost operations (we can not truncate it).

Comment: what about a simple SQL trigger that writes your log information to a table in the database?  Are you really sure this will be slower than a Java trigger (starting a Java process adds a lot of extra overhead, and writing to an ordinary file will be slower than writing to the DB)?

Comment: Well, @dan1111, thank you for your advices. I'll try next week your idea with logging into table, plus using table context switching for achieving fast truncating of processed data.

Comment: If you need a logging system for DB2, take a lot at this: https://github.com/angoca/log4db2

Comment: @AngocA, thanks for your advice, but we don't need simple logging, but something more complex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, I have to give a negative answer to my own question.
According to this paper: [Static and non-final variables in a Java routine](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/dzichelp/v2r2/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2.doc.java/src/tpc/imjcc_javastaticnonfinalvars.htm) exactly what I'd like to do is **impossible**.

Answer (score 1):

DB2 will force multi-process model execution of your stored procedures.

I would suggest you to just send your data to a message queue, and have an application listening to that queue handle the data and do the logging. Take a look at for example [RabbitMQ](http://www.rabbitmq.com/devtools.html#java-dev), [Apache ActiveMQ](http://activemq.apache.org/), or [ZeroMQ](http://www.zeromq.org/).

This would be probably trivial to implement, but it requires usually that you have a daemon with your application logic running. This is true unless you configure the message queue product to spawn your application logic automatically - which is usually possible with message queue products but requires a bit more configuration.

Comment: Well, actually this is a good idea, but we don't want to use MQ technology. An any way I'll +1 your answer. Thanks.